# Solr: split category data and product data over different cores/instances?

Tags: solr

I have a webshop with multiple different productcategories.
For each category I have a description, metadata, image and some more category specific data.
Right now, my data-config.xml looks as below.

However, I think this way I'm indexing all category specific data for each product individually, so taking up a lot more space than needed.
I'm now considering to move the indexing and storing of category specific data to a separate solr core/instance, this way I have basically separated the product specific data and the category data.

Is this reasoning correct? Is it better to move the category specific data outside this core/instance?

```
<document name="shopitems">
    <entity name="shopitem" pk="id" query="select * from products" >        
        <field name="id" column="ID" />
        <field name="articlenr" column="articlenr" />           
        <field name="title" column="title" />

        <entity name="catdescription" query="select 
            pagetitle_de as cat_pagetitle_de,pagetitle_en as cat_pagetitle_en
            ,description as cat_description
            ,metadescription as cat_metadescription 
            FROM products_custom_cat_descriptions where articlegroup = '${shopitem.articlegroup}'">
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Comment: How large is your index (size/no. of documents)? Is it an issue today? How are you expecting the data to grow over time? It might not be as large of an issue as you think..

Comment: I'm on 247MB now with ~180.000 products, but that's only with a bit of category data. I expect the category specific data to triple. Total documents will probably double/triple. But would it not be better design to split it? Or are you saying that in the current scenario I won't have to make another (perhaps expensive) request to Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your implementation will be easier if you flatten (de-normalize) everything, as you did. If you spin off the categories in a different core, Solr becomes harder to use - you will need extra queries, extra client code, faceting won't work so easily, etc - all of which will result in a performance hit, on top of the extra implementation difficulties.

From the numbers you give (staying under 1GB index size? it's not that big), I would definitely not go the way of splitting out the category data, it will make your life harder, for not much practical gain.